# Access Denied: You have not been setup to use this system VB.Net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, permissions, access-denied, application-security

I have certain users accounts that are unable to run a VB.net application from our network drive. When the problem user account executes the Click-once application the program begins to execute creates the file lock on the ms access database but then the system throws the following error:

**Access Denied** in the windows title bar and displaying a message that says: "**You have not been setup to use this system. Please contact your system Administrator.**"

This occurs for these trouble user accounts regardless of the workstation I am logged into. I have narrowed it down to the specific application because I am able to run another VB.Net application that uses the same ms access database.

- I have even deleted the user account from AD and then using the Copy user feature 
  recreated the user account by copying from a user account that runs the application fine.

I also removed the Click-once security and republished the application. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I am out of options to try.  Thank you much...

Comment: That message sounds like it's generated within the application itself so the reason for it could be anything. Do you have access to the sourcecode, or the original developer?

Comment: You've probably already checked this but do the problem user accounts have write access to the share? I'm thinking if there account isn't allowed to write then their connection to Access couldn't update the locking file.

Comment: Thank you all. I discovered it was the application.  The dipstick programmer (that was me) placed a generic error if the userID was note found in a table while starting the app thus making the error message almost seeming system generated. It was trigger because the userID was entered incorrectly.  I have since changed this error message.

Thank you much again for your suggestions...